# Expand array by adding another array as new dimension

Tags: numpy

I have two Numpy arrays `data` and `labels` defined as follows:

```
data=np.zeros((100,256,2))
labels=np.ones((100,10))
```

`data` and `labels` need to be concatenated to form an array of shape `(100,256,2,10)`. The intuition is that I have `100` 2D-data points each of shape `(256,2)` each of which has a label of shape `(10)`. I tried `concatenate`, `hstack`, `vstack` etc. which all don't seem to fit due to shape constraints.

Comment: Don't think you are looking for a concatenation, think it would be indexing. Get an mcve and try to manual verify things.

Comment: Experiment with much smaller arrays, ones that you can print.

Comment: I dont think it is possible to combine arrays of shapes `(256, 2)` and `(10)` to a new array of shape `(256, 2, 10)`

Comment: The (100,256,2,10) array would have to replicate the `data` values 10 times, and the `labels` 512 times.  I don't think that's what you want.  What do you hope to do with the combined array?